# How to fill a path with objects

Tags: path, instances

I would like to fill the spiral path with the duplicates of crystal objects (as in array modifier).How can I get it?
I am using Blender 2.83.

Thank you[image]

Comment: Array modifier + curve modifier?

Comment: Look at the example of tentacle from Blender Manuel. The included Blend file should show what you need.
 https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/array.html

Comment: For your information https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-questions-should-be-definitely-off-topic/6#6 .

Comment: I tried array modifier + Curve modifier. But the number of object duplicates is not enough to fill the entire path.

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/array.html#options